# Is there a way to use NetBeans DIFF tool as an external diff editor for TortiseSVN, or other editor?

Tags: netbeans, tortoisesvn, diff

... or perhaps a way to launch NetBeans through a middle-man app and open up a BASE and LOCAL file in the DIFF editor ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it is the style of the netbeans diff tool that you like, have a look at the free [Perforce Merge Tool.](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/products/merge.html)

[image: P4Merge]
<sub>(source: [perforce.com](http://www.perforce.com/images/products/p4merge/main.gif))</sub>

In TortoiseSVN settings set the external diff viewer to:

```
C:\Program Files\Perforce\P4Merge.exe -dw %base %mine
```

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the diff tool used by TortoiseSVN in the settings (External Programs -> Diff Viewer).

The [TortoiseSVN help file](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-settings.html#tsvn-dug-settings-progs) explains the different parameters that can be passed to the external diff tool via the command line.

Comment: Ya, I saw that, but i can't find documentation on NetBeans to be able to pass in the values correctly ... I'll have to try a few different combination to see if it works ...